# Power Point 2010 youtube embeding problem

Tags: vba, youtube, powerpoint

I know this is more programming related site but I couldnt think of a better place to ask this... anyways, Im trying to use the new Embed from video site feature but it seems to be disabled. Please help?

[image]

Comment: I have just uninstalled the 64-bit office, and installed the 32-bit office, and the "Video From Website" option is still disabled... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess I'll turn this into a programming question for the benefit of others needing this programmatically as well.

The most likely cause here is that you're using an x64 version of PowerPoint 2010. The [help file](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/embed-a-video-in-your-presentation-HA010374729.aspx) states:

> PowerPoint 2010 64-bit is not
>   compatible with 32-bit versions of
>   QuickTime or Flash. You must install a
>   64-bit version of QuickTime or Flash,
>   or a 32-bit version of PowerPoint
>   2010.

Kind of pointless to say that because neither Flash or QT have 64-bit versions. That said, you can still embed (actually, "link to") a file programmatically by using code, such as:

```
Sub InsertWebVideo()
Dim sl As Slide
Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(28)
sl.Shapes.AddMediaObjectFromEmbedTag EmbedTag:= _
        "<object width='640' height='385'>" & _
        "<param name='movie' value='http://www.youtube.com/v/gejJM3n2LHU&hl=en_US&fs=1&'>" & _
        "</param><param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'></param>" & _
        "<param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'></param>" & _
        "<embed src='http://www.youtube.com/v/gejJM3n2LHU&hl=en_US&fs=1&' " & _
        "type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' " & _
        "allowfullscreen='true' width='640' height='385'></embed></object>"
End Sub
```

The issue is that this just doesn't work at all on x64 - an object appears on the slide, but nothing happens. Embedding Silverlight doesn't seem to work though as Windows Media Player kicks an error. If you happen to have a WMV on a website, give that a try with `<embed/>` code using something like the code above.